# Using Powershell to parse through a variable

Tags: regex, powershell

I have script that goes through my emails then returns the body of each of the emails that matches my query. The body looks something like this

```
Recipients:     last.first@email-place.com 
Attachment  Report.pdf 
Timestamp of Message:   18 January 2016 

Recipients:     Anothername.first@email-place.com 
Attachment  Report2.pdf 
Timestamp of Message:   18 January 2016
```

I'm trying to either get each line of the body in a custom-object or just extract the email addresses to a variable to do more work with.
Any ideas.

Comment: Is it returning an array of single line strings, an array of multi-line strings (one per email body), or a single multi-line string with all of the bodies?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. How can I tell?

Comment: @mjolinor - I believe it is an array of multi-line strings

Comment: If you send it to a variable, what is the .count property of that vaiable?

Comment: @mjolinor - The count equals the number of emails found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use a multi-line regex to capture the data, and then create a custom object from the captures:

Edit: Updated with example using `ForEach` loop.

```
$regex = @'
(?ms)Recipients:\s+(.+?)\s* 
Attachment\s+(.+?)\s* 
Timestamp of Message:\s+(.+)
'@ 

$Result=
ForEach ($text in $variable)
 {
   if ($text -match  $regex)
     {
       [PSCustomObject]@{
        Recipients = $matches[1]
        Attachment = $matches[2]
        Timestamp  = $matches[3]
        }
     }
 }

Recipients                        Attachment  Timestamp      
----------                        ----------  ---------      
Anothername.first@email-place.com Report2.pdf 18 January 2016
```

Comment: In your example how do I add the variable from the output of my original query to the $text array

Comment: Since your variable is an array, you can run it through a ForEach loop.I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: Had a copy/paste fail and left out the regex when I did the update.  Fixed.

Comment: Man - I can't give you a +1 yet since I don't have enough of a rep yet. But that is awesome. Thanks

Comment: See my Answer below, but it's also a question sinc eI'm trying to add each output object to a variable with the properties